# Unable to install Curb on Linux 14.04 using apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev

Tags: linux, curb

I am trying to install Curb using command apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
on Linux 14.04

Detail below

**apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev**
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree
 Reading state information... Done

Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

libcurl4-openssl-dev : Depends: libidn11-dev but it is not
    installable
    Depends: libkrb5-dev but it is not going to be installed
    Depends: libldap2-dev but it is not installable
    Depends: librtmp-dev but it is not installable
    Depends: libssl-dev but it is not going to be installed
    Depends: zlib1g-dev but it is not installable

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.